# how to compare rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to compare 2 rows and I've got trouble doing that.

I have these rows:

```
Name                StartDate                  EndDate
Ian Buckley     2009-10-30 00:00:00.000     2014-01-09 00:00:00.000
Ian Buckley     2014-01-10 00:00:00.000     NULL
Neil Kent       2009-10-17 00:00:00.000     2014-01-09 00:00:00.000
Neil Kent       2014-01-10 00:00:00.000     NULL
```

What I'm trying to do is to check for every name if the `StartDate` (on the line with `EndDate` null) is after the `EndDate` (on the line with an actual `EndDate`)

> Eg: For Ian Buckley 2014-01-10 00:00:00.000 > 2014-01-09 00:00:00.000
>   and that's ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a PK or some kind of row counter? Is this the entire row?  Does this get what you wanted?   `Select t1.*, t2.* from yourtable t1 inner join yourtable t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t2.endDate is null and t2.StartDate > t1.enddate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT      *, (CASE WHEN t1.StartDate > t2.EndDate THEN 'Ok' ELSE 'Not Ok' END) AS isOk
FROM        dbo.TABLE_1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN   dbo.TABLE_1 AS t2 ON t2.name = t1.name AND t2.EndDate IS NOT NULL

WHERE t1.EndDate IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Join your table against itself. You have to make sure that each row does cause a join condition because of itself. I normally would have added a `t1.primary_key <> t2.primary_key`

```
Select t1.*, t2.* from yourtable t1 
inner join yourtable t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t2.endDate is null 
     and t2.StartDate > t1.enddate
```